# highcharts always console error ablout bubble_compiled.js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I write a pie chart in my app
But it always error with `bubble_compiled.js`
when I click in pie, it don't has animate,
and it show `Uncaught TypeError: a.target.className.indexOf is not a function`
Why?

Comment: Could you please show us a code sample? What have you done?

Comment: Or live demo with the issue would be great. Also, where did you get bubble_compiles.js file?

Answer (score 26):

I've experienced the same error when clicking on my D3 charts.

`bubble_compiled.js` is part of the [Google Translate Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en). Disabling/removing this extension will make the error go away, but this error should not affect your site at all.

This error is occurring because the extension has a mousedown listener which tries to check if the target element has the class "jfk-bubble-closebtn".

Relevant code in the extension ([full source here](http://pastebin.com/UcASmvyq)):

```
P(window, "mousedown", function(a) {
    var b = Ub(document, "gtx-trans");
    b && (ec(b, a.target) ? a.preventDefault() : (Tc(b),
    dc(b)));
    -1 != a.target.className.indexOf("jfk-bubble-closebtn") && a.preventDefault()
}
```

Since you are using Highcharts, you might be trying to click on an SVG element. The type of an SVG class name is `SVGAnimatedString`, which unlike `String` does not have an `indexOf` method. So when the extension tries to call it, it fails because it does not exist.

See also: [Chrome and a TypeError due to SVGAnimatedString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279566/2506493)